# OSX iTerm2 zsh when I press F5~F12 it will input some strange automatically?

Tags: macos, iterm2

When I press F5~F8, it will input `~` for me automatically

When I press F9, it will input `0~` for me automatically

When I press F10, it will input `1~` for me automatically

When I press F11, it will input `3~` for me automatically

When I press F12, it will input `4~` for me automatically

I don't know why does it happen, I already unset all Fkeys in the setting of the system and iTerm2.

Comment: Unless your OS-X based preferences are assigning functions to those keys, Terminal and iTerm does basically the same thing for those functions and spit out the key code. If you want those to not do that, just assign them to 'Ingore' in the ITerm Profile Preferences and clear any assigned functions in the OS-X preferences.

Comment: @RobertN If I assign them to 'Ingore' in the ITerm Profile Preferences, how can I map them to vim or tmux after it?